# Images appear pink on iOS in Flutter application

Tags: ios, flutter, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St78x.jpg)I'm encountering an issue where certain images in my Flutter application appear pink when running on iOS devices. This behavior is intermittent and doesn't consistently affect all images.
I've searched for similar issues but haven't found a definitive solution. Any insights, suggestions, or solutions to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I expected the images to display correctly without any color distortions or anomalies, particularly the pink tint observed on certain iOS devices

Comment: hi  khurshid shah , please share video or screenshot for more explaination this problem.

Comment: @EsmaeilAhmadipour image attach

Comment: Can you share image format, image url for the images showing pink color

Comment: @AizanSagheer its come from server and its shopify images